# How do I make the top 10px of a div invisible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to only make the top portion of a div invisible, I am using JQuery if that help.  The div must still reserve spacing so as to not shrink in size.

EDIT:  Everything must stay in place so I can't use something simple like BR or margin.

Comment: Please give us your code and a better idea of exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Well, it's pretty strait forward, I have a div, and it got some text/stuff in it, and I need everything to stay in place but the first 10px down from the top to be invisible.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: It would help to know what _is_ visible. The background of the DIV? If it is, you could use some kind of CSS3 gradient to abruptly end/begin the background color http://gradients.glrzad.com/ or use a background image that is transparent at the top. You could also move the div down and the div content up (negative margin), but I don't know if this would help your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another div inside it with `position: relative;width: 100%;height: 10px;`. Set the z-index to 9999.

Comment: This is what I thought... I was hoping there was a more elegant way, but it works.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu glad to hear it. It is not elegant, but is a perfectly accepted workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top: 10px` in the CSS, perhaps?

Comment: I can't use margin because it push everything down.  I should probably clarify that I need everything to stay in place.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu your reply makes no sense. Either the answer is margin-top, padding-top, or there is something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

```
margin-top: -10px;
```

then set the `padding-top` of the inner visible content to 10px to move it down.

wrap the entire div with another div and add `overflow: hidden;` to it's style